# How can I erase q in this case? and sort the file alphabetically?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that gets an input from a user and put it into a file in an alphabetical order.(Names.txt is a file that have a list of given names in an alphabetical order)

Here is what I have done so far.

```
def main():
    outfile = open("Names.txt","a")
    name1 = 0
    while True:
        if name1 != "q":
            name1 = input("Enter a first name, if you want to quit, enter q: ")
            list1 = []
            list1.append("\n"+name1)
            outfile.writelines(list1)
        else:
            break
    list1.sort()    
main()
```

Suppose I entered Brian, Tyler and q to quit.
But I still have q in a file even though I used break in a while loop.
Also, in order to put inputs in a proper location, I used sort but there is no change..

What's wrong with my code? Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could move the `name1 = input` line above the `if nameq != "q"` line

Comment: Why are you resetting `list1` to `[]` on every read?

Comment: Thanks, I changed all of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

The first is that you should check `name1 != "q"` after getting the input. The way you do it, you get the input, append it to the list, write it into the file and then you check if the name is q or not in that order, you should check before appending it to the list.

The second mistake is that you are overwriting the list at every iteration when you do `list1 = []`, therefore you will at most have one name into the list at any time, you should initialize the list before the loop.

Finally, you should write the list into the file **after** you sort the list, and not in every iteration of your loop. The way it is now, the names will not be sorted in the file. Also, the file should be closed when you are done writing in it using `outfile.close()`.

The code should be something like this:

```
def main():
    outfile = open("Names.txt","a")
    list1 = []
    while True:
        name1 = input("Enter a first name, if you want to quit, enter q: ")
        if name1 != "q":
            list1.append(name1+"\n")
        else:
            break
    list1.sort()
    for name in list1:
        outfile.writelines(name)
    outfile.close()
main()
```

Comment: Was the file "Names.txt" empty before you executed the code?, if you use parameter "a" in the line `outfile = open("Names.txt","a")` it does not overwrite the file, it just appends new names (in order) after the ones already existing in the file. Therefore if the file was not empty the names may not be ordered.

Comment: Then there are two options, if you change the parameter `"a"` for `"w"` it will overwrite the file completely, keeping only the names of the last run of the code. If you want to keep all the names and have them ordered in the file, you will need to read the names in the file and append them to `list1` before you ask for new names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, name1 is assigned first and written to file and the check (name1 != "q") is breaking only in next iteration. 
And then you are sorting and doing nothing. You need to sort the list and then write to file to see sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `input()` out of `if` block.

```
def main():
    outfile = open("Names.txt","a")
    while True:
        name1 = input("Enter a first name, if you want to quit, enter q: ")
        if name1 != "q":
            list1 = []
            list1.append(name1+"\n")
            outfile.writelines(list1)
        else:
            break
    list1.sort()
main()
```